# Why does the RMSE value goes high?

Tags: regression, multivariate-analysis, prediction, rms

I have been trying to predict the glucose values of patients by using regression algorithms. I used Support Vector Regression (RMSE: 65), Logistic Regression (RMSE: 86), Linear Regression(RMSE: 64) and Random Forest Regressor(RMSE: 72). So as you noted the minimum RMSE I got is 64 which is from Linear Regression. I did Hyperparameter tuning and Standardize the features using the Standard scaler but still, no reasonable RMSE value can be seen(Between 60 - 70). Any help to reduce the RMSE value? The image of the dataset I have is added. It contains about 2100 records.

[image]

The code I typed for reading and scaling the features is given below

`data = pd.read_csv('output_morning-readings.csv')
data = data.drop(['Insulin_t-2','Breakfast','Lunch_bd','Dinner','Event'],axis=1)`

I have dropped the above columns since I found that it doesn't have a much effect on the target by a correlation matrix.

Then I converted the columns which contain binary and numerical categories in to the data type category

`data['Gender'] = data['Gender'].astype('category')
data['None'] = data['None'].astype('category')
data['Low'] = data['Low'].astype('category')
data['Medium'] = data['Medium'].astype('category')
data['High'] = data['High'].astype('category')
data['Meal'] = data['Meal'].astype('category')`

Then I standardized the non-categorical data as below

`from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc=StandardScaler()
data[['Insulin_t-1','Insulin_t','Glucose_t-3','Glucose_t-2','Glucose_t-1']] = sc.fit_transform(data[['Insulin_t-1','Insulin_t','Glucose_t-3','Glucose_t-2','Glucose_t-1']])`

The COLUMN Glucose_t is the target which I want to predict. I didn't standardized the Glucose_t (target) column and age, weight(features). Is there something I have done wrong?

Comment: Seems to be the same as your other question? [Unable to make accurate predictions?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/449015/unable-to-make-accurate-predictions)

Comment: Yes it might be the same but as you see i have made a reasonable progress. So can you give me any suggestions to reduce the RMSE?

Comment: Re-posting a closed question isn't how this website works. The [help] explains that questions should be improved: closed questions should be edited and that edited questions are eligible to be re-opened.

Comment: Can you give us a code as to how you standardized your features and fitted your models? If you standardized (i.e. scaled and centered) all features and then response, then RMSE values around 60-70 should be impossible.

Comment: Additionally, even if you do everything correctly, sometimes there just isn't enough information in the data to fit a useful model. So "high" RMSE (if you scaled all your predictors + reponse, that would be around 1) is sometimes unavoidable.

Comment: Yeah sure I'll add it right now @AdamB.

Comment: Hey @AdamB. can I add the code blocks as comments down here or is there any other way?

Comment: @AdamB. I edited my post with the relevant code blocks